# Java Swing - How to make the JButton's boundaries invisible?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, windowbuilder

In the screenshot below, you can see four buttons in the selected area. I want to mimic this kind of buttons in my GUI application. Each of these buttons has an image on them (play,stop, forward, rewind). I can use the icon property of the button to add an image to it.

When the user hovers the mouse pointer over a button, three things happen:

1. it changes color- I don't need this feature.
2. It displays a tool tip. I know how to do it by using the tooltip
   text property of a button.
3. Most importantly, **these buttons don't have a border around them,
   That is their bounds are not visible at all.** ***It's just the image
   which is visible. I want to do something like this.*** *But when I add
   an image to a button, its border does not go away* (I mean it's
   bounds are clearly visible in the form of a line - as you can see in
   the second image)

**So what property of an button should I manipulate, or what method should I use, to make its borders (and every visible trace of the button except the image present on it) invisible?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A border is painted when [`setBorderPainted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setBorderPainted%28boolean%29) is set to true, otherwise not:

**`setBorderPainted`:**

> Sets the `borderPainted` property. If `true` and the button has a border,
>   the border is painted. The default value for the `borderPainted`
>   property is `true`.  Some look and feels might not support the
>   `borderPainted` property, in which case they ignore this.

Note that some look and feels may ignore this property.

**Update:**

The default look and feel is called `CrossPlatformLookAndFeel`. This is not a look and feel but an indicator of the default one. What you get as default depends on the platform you are using. See [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for details. I personally loke the [Nimbus Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html), but I have encountered some problems with it. I am not sure if it respects `setBorderPainted`, but I will not be surprised if it does not.

Comment: I am completely new to Java Swing and am using Eclipse Window Builder to make a GUI. I am not sure what is the default look and feel. So I'll be grateful if you can share if this works with the default look and feel?

Comment: @Zarah The default L&F is system dependent. On Windows it's `MetalLookAndFeel`.

Comment: You may also wish to use `setContentPainted` as well

Comment: Edited post to add some details.